# Detect non alphabetic characters in a mixed string

Tags: c++

Very simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
string name;

cout << "Enter first and last name" << endl;
getline(cin, name);

return 0;
}
```

As you can see I want my user to type in their first and last name which will include white spaces. I would like to check it for numeric characters and if any are entered, throw up an error. An example input could be: "J0hn Sm1th" which would of course display an error.

I know I will have to use isAlpha() and I can get it to work if just numbers or if just letters are entered, but not when they are combined.

Comment: Iterate through and check `!isalpha()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>

bool check_name(const string& str)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
        if (!((str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') ||
              (str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') ||
               str[i]==' ' || str[i]=='-' ))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly! If it detects more than one error it throws up my error message for every incorrect character.. How do I fix this? Ignore this, I fixed it!

Comment: If you just do: `if (!check_name(name)) cout << "error\n";` it will throw the message only once (if an incorrect character was detected).

Answer (score 11):

If you have C++11, go with `std::all_of(name.begin(), name.end(), isalpha)`.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed. Something new to try out, thanks :)

Comment: This wouldn't allow a name like Jean-Luc Picard though

Comment: @GuyGreer, create your own predicate that uses `isalpha` and `ishyphen` (not a real one) then.

Comment: ^^^ you could use a fancy lambda function ^^^

Comment: what do I need to include to make this work? `#include <*****>`

Comment: @blanksby you need to include `algorithm` and `cctype`

Comment: I've implemented the code and it traps the numbers when they are entered. But when only letters are entered with a space it still traps it..? Without the space it works perfectly.

Comment: -1 incomplete & incorrect. incompleteness: should mention generally necessary call to setlocale. incorrect: except for basic ASCII, which isn't in use, the above exhibits Undefined Behavior (e.g. for Norwegian characters). the function needs to be wrapped so that the actual argument to `isalpha` is guaranteed non-negative or EOF.

Comment: @blanksby `std::all_of(name.begin(), name.end(), [](char c) { return isalpha(c) || isspace(c); })`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf No it does not. While isalpha/isspace are affected by locale, std::getline is as well.

Comment: @KlemensBaum: the things you mention are irrelevant to the UB.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the lowercase and uppercase values are same or not, For non-alphabetic characters they will be same